# How to pass lambda expression in hasdynamicproperty function In OData?

Tags: odata, lambda

As I am passing below expression in hasdynamicproperty function. but I am getting an error Unsupported Expression NodeType.

ucs.EntityType.HasDynamicProperties((x) => new Dictionary() { { "HasPendingServiceOrder", x.ServiceOrders.Any(y => y.DateCancelled == null && y.IdSoTypeResult == null) } });

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajat I think your usage of `HasDynamicProperties` method is off. This method is applied when you're building an Edm model using non-convention model builder by directly calling the fluent APIs of `ODataModelBuilder`.

Like the docs indicate, you use `HasDynamicProperties` method to *Add a dynamic property dictionary property*

For instance, consider the CLR class like the one below with an `IDictionary<string, object>` property

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
}
```

You can build an open entity type as follows:

```
var customerEntity = builder.EntityType<Customer>();
customerEntity.HasKey(d => d.Id);
customerEntity.HasProperty(d => d.Name);
customerEntity.HasDynamicProperties(d => d.DynamicProperties);
```

**UPDATE:**

For further reading on Edm model builders visit the OData docs site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/model-builder-abstract)